# formatting text in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I hope all is well.

I was wondering if anyone could help me. I have the following javascript  function that I am trying to apply to a div nested within a list view.

My javascript function:

```
function viewPost(val1) {


var msg = val1.innerHTML;
console.log(msg);

    // disable < and > to prevent scripting attacks
    msg = msg.replace(/\</gi, "&lt;");
    msg = msg.replace(/\>/gi, "&gt;");

    // preserve new lines
    msg = msg.replace(/\n/gi, "<br />");

    // Basic BBCodes.

    // head large
    msg = msg.replace(/\[hdlg\]/gi, '<h1>');
    msg = msg.replace(/\[\/hdlg\]/gi, '</h1>');
    // head medium
    msg = msg.replace(/\[hdmd\]/gi, '<h2>');
    msg = msg.replace(/\[\/hdmd\]/gi, '</h2>');
    // head small
    msg = msg.replace(/\[hdsm\]/gi, '<h3>');
    msg = msg.replace(/\[\/hdsm\]/gi, '</h3>');
    // bold text
    msg = msg.replace(/\[b\]/gi, "<strong>");
    msg = msg.replace(/\[\/b\]/gi, "</strong>");
    // italic text
    msg = msg.replace(/\[i\]/gi, "<em>");
    msg = msg.replace(/\[\/i\]/gi, "</em>");
    // underlined text
    msg = msg.replace(/\[u\]/gi, "<u>");
    msg = msg.replace(/\[\/u\]/gi, "</u>");
    // centre text
    msg = msg.replace(/\[c\]/gi, '<p style="text-align:center;">');
    msg = msg.replace(/\[\/c\]/gi, "</p>");
    // left align text
    msg = msg.replace(/\[l\]/gi, '<p style="text-align:left;">');
    msg = msg.replace(/\[\/l\]/gi, "</p>");
    // right align text
    msg = msg.replace(/\[r\]/gi, '<p style="text-align:right;">');
    msg = msg.replace(/\[\/r\]/gi, "</p>");
    // justify text
    msg = msg.replace(/\[j\]/gi, '<p style="text-align:justify;">');
    msg = msg.replace(/\[\/j\]/gi, "</p>");
    // code blocks
    msg = msg.replace(/\[code\]/gi, '<div style="background:#484848;color:#ffffff;text-align:left;border-radius:8px;padding:10px;">');
    msg = msg.replace(/\[\/code\]/gi, '</div>');
    // def lists
    msg = msg.replace(/\[def\]/gi, '<dl>');
    msg = msg.replace(/\[\/def\]/gi, '</dl>');
    // def term
    msg = msg.replace(/\[term\]/gi, '<dt>');
    msg = msg.replace(/\[\/term\]/gi, '</dt>');
    // def description
    msg = msg.replace(/\[desc\]/gi, '<dd>');
    msg = msg.replace(/\[\/desc\]/gi, '</dd>');
    // unordered list
    msg = msg.replace(/\[unord\]/gi, '<ul>');
    msg = msg.replace(/\[\/unord\]/gi, '</ul>');
    // ordered list
    msg = msg.replace(/\[ord\]/gi, '<ol>');
    msg = msg.replace(/\[\/ord\]/gi, '</ol>');
    // list item
    msg = msg.replace(/\[item\]/gi, '<li>');
    msg = msg.replace(/\[\/item\]/gi, '</li>');
    // links
    msg = msg.replace(/\[url=(.*?)\](.*?)/gi, '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$2');
    msg = msg.replace(/\[\/url\]/gi, '</a>');
    // images 
    msg = msg.replace(/\[postpic=(.*?)\sclass=(.*?)\stitle=(.*?)\salt=(.*?)\sstyle=(.*?)\]/gi, '<img src="/images/postAssets/$1" class="$2" title="$3" alt="$4" style="$5" />');
    msg = msg.replace(/\[\/postpic\]/gi, "");
    // font colour [colour=COL] [/colour]
    msg = msg.replace(/\[colour=(.*?)\]/gi, '<span style="color:$1;">');
    msg = msg.replace(/\[\/colour\]/gi, '</span>');
    // tables
    msg = msg.replace(/\[table\]/gi, '<table style="padding: 5px;">');
    msg = msg.replace(/\[\/table\]/gi, '</table>');
    // table row
    msg = msg.replace(/\[trow\]/gi, '<tr style="border:1px solid #000000;">');
    msg = msg.replace(/\[\/trow\]/gi, '</tr>');
    // table header
    msg = msg.replace(/\[thead\]/gi, '<th style="padding: 5px;">');
    msg = msg.replace(/\[\/thead\]/gi, '</th>');
    // table data
    msg = msg.replace(/\[tdata\]/gi, '<td style="padding: 5px;">');
    msg = msg.replace(/\[\/tdata\]/gi, '</td>');
    // subscript
    msg = msg.replace(/\[sub\]/gi, '<sub>');
    msg = msg.replace(/\[\/sub\]/gi, '</sub>');
    // superscript
    msg = msg.replace(/\[sup\]/gi, '<sup>');
    msg = msg.replace(/\[\/sup\]/gi, '</sup>');

    val1.innerHTML = msg;

    console.log(val1.innerHTML);


}
```

to call this function I have in the page the following javascript:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("displayBox");
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        viewPost(divs.item[i]);
    }


    });
```

My asp.net listview:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lstPosts" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceholder" GroupItemCount="3" GroupPlaceholderID="groupPlaceholder" OnPagePropertiesChanging="lstPosts_PagePropertiesChanging">
            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                <div>
                    <p>No data was returned.</p>
                </div>
            </EmptyDataTemplate>

            <GroupTemplate>
                <div class="row">
                    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
                </div>
            </GroupTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>

                <a id="postLink" href='<%#: GetRouteUrl("BlogPostRoute", new {postid = Eval("postID")}) %>'>
                    <div id="lstBox" class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <h2><%# Eval("PostTitle") %></h2>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">


                                <div class="displayBox"><%# Eval("PostContent") %></div>

                           </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>

            </ItemTemplate>
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <div class="row">
                    <div id="groupPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" style="width: 100%">
                        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="groupPlaceholder" runat="server" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server" PagedControlID="lstPosts" PageSize="12">

                        <Fields>

                            <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Link" ShowFirstPageButton="false" ShowPreviousPageButton="true"
                                ShowNextPageButton="false" />

                            <asp:NumericPagerField ButtonType="Link" />

                            <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Link" ShowNextPageButton="true" ShowLastPageButton="false" ShowPreviousPageButton="false" />

                        </Fields>

                    </asp:DataPager>
                </div>
            </LayoutTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, or right for that matter. any assistance would be awesome. The function should format the text as defined by the regex. At the moment its not able to find the div to format its text.

Comment: [`HTMLCollection.item`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) is a function. You need parentheses to invoke a function: `viewPost(divs.item(i));`, or without item method: `viewPost(divs[i]);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code from `divs.item[i]` to: `divs[i]`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("displayBox");
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    viewPost(divs[i]);
}


});
```